# SSRS 2008 Stop Tablix from Exporting to CSV

Tags: reporting-services

I have two Tablix controls on my SSRS report. I want one of them to export and one not to export. I have accomplished this by setting the hidden property on the one I want to export to:

```
"=Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive = True"
```

and the one I do not want to export to:

```
"=Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive = False"
```

This works perfectly when I export to Excel, however CSV simply ignores these values and exports both Tablix controls. I need to know how I can force CSV to only export one Tablix control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `visibility.hidden` property of the tablix you don't want to export to CSV to:

```
=(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV")
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx

Comment: Trying to reproduce this now (as I thought I had done in the past also), this approach does not work. See this documentation on how you cannot use expressions to control visibility for csv and xml: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx. For CSV, I suggest working around the problem by using a parameter asking what the intended export format will be, and based on the value of the parameter, you can hide report elements.

Answer (score 2):

Format options such as expressions on visibility are ignored for CSV rendering methods.  CSV rendering methods are essentially data flows, so you can suppress elements that you don't want to include in CSV files by changing the DataElementOutput from Auto, the default value, to NoOutput.

Answer (score 1):

You can't conditionally set the DataElementOutput, but you can conditionally set the tablix filters. That will leave the header row in the csv output, but trims the data rows.